# pdfjam corrupting libreoffice pdf file

Tags: pdftex, unicode, pdfpages, font-encodings, libre-office

Running a simple pdf file containing unicode(non-Latin) characters of the Libertinus Serif font though pdfjam produces a corrupted file in which the unicode characters are not encoded correctly. The pdf file produced says Encoding:Custom instead of the expected Encoding:Builtin as in the source pdf file.

This can be reproduced by using LibreOffice 7.5.2.2 to produce the source pdf file and then passing it through pdfjam 3.03 in the current texlive distribution. If LibreOffice 7.4 is used then the pdfjammed file is not corrupt. This version of LO gave a non-standard name to the font embedded in the pdf it produced; LO 7.5.5.2 corrects this, and somehow this use of the standard font name seems to cause the texlive Type 1 font to be inserted in the pdf file by pdfjam and upset the encoding.

I wonder where the bug lies.

More details:
The source document is, for example, the text:
Question 123
in a LibreOffice writer document with font specified as "Libertinus Serif:onum=1&pnum=1". This document is exported as pdf. The pdf file produced shows the text "Question 123" with a long-tailed "Q" and lowercase numerals "123". These are the characters which are corrupted in the output file when the LO 7.5 pdf file is used as input file for pdfjam.

I'd like to add more information: specifically to attach the 2 pdf files, one produced by libreoffice 7.5 and the other by libreoffice 7.4. Then use these files as "input.pdf" in command: pdfjam -o out.pdf input.pdf.  The one produced from LO 7.4 gives a correct out.pdf (ie same size file more or less, and unicode chars displaying correctly) but the out.pdf from processing input.pdf from LO 7.5 is much bigger (goes from < 6kB to > 600kB) and the unicode chars are garbled. Also the out.pdf property changes from Encoding:Builtin to Encoding:Custom. If it were possible I'd attach the pdf files.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you show us a small complete example of LaTeX code that produces this error? It helps so that people can copy and paste it in on their systems to reproduce and troubleshoot for fixes, there is an edit button next to share and before follow at the bottom of your question :)

Comment: your question should not only *claim* that it can be reproduced, but also add all needed info and files so that we can actually do it.

Comment: Did pdfjam ever guarantee that the PDF font encoding is fixed? If not you can't really say it's a bug right?

Comment: I suspect pdfjam is using the pdf(La)TeX engine and that the problem I have would disappear if  Lua(La)TeX were called instead - but my knowledge of these matters is not good enough to verify, modify or work out why...

Comment: @Bernard You can choose the TeX-engine used by pdfjam with option `--latex`. See also `pdfjam -h` for the help message.

Comment: @AndreasMatthias Great! The solution I needed!. (I should have read the documentation of pdfjam once I'd suspected it was an engine selection matter! Thanks.